# unable to push to git repo | node package open error

Tags: git, express, npm, express-generator

I set up my project with the Express generator and everything was fine when creating the repository on GitHub and I was able to clone it to my desktop and generate the folder structure. When I did a lot of work on my app (Pug, node, express) I wanted to add all the files in my project with "git add ." and I get this error in my console:

```
 error: open("node_modules/.bin/acorn"): Invaliid argument
 error: unable to index file node_modules/.bin/ac/acorn
 fatal: updating files failed
```

As I can't add the files I can't commit or push them either.

I'm running windows 10.

edit: If I try to move the files to a new file in windows explorer I get this error https://snag.gy/T1dI3M.jpg so I guess it's something to do with the acorn package but I don't know if I can delete it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `generated the folder structure`. Can you add screenshot of how your project is structured `ls ` from root of your project and what outout you get when you do `git status`

Comment: Hi, late reply, sorry,  I couldn't solve this issue so i deleted the project and the repo and started again.What I meant was I used this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html to generate the project at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that "node_modules" must be kept in ".gitignore" file. So that while performing push operation node_modules folder will get ignored and updated to git.

Comment: Yes this could have possibly solved the issue, I didn't understand what you meant at the time.

Comment: This is not a good solution for long term storage though. Node modules are not always available online and should be kept with a repository that is being archived.